# How to activate the Gedit terminal plugin?

Tags: gedit

I have the following packages installed:

- `gedit`
- `gedit-common`
- `gedit-plugins`

In Ubuntu 12.04 with these packages installed all that was needed was to activate the terminal plugin and the press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to show the bottom panel. This isn't the case with Ubuntu 13.10 (Gedit 3.8.3) and I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After you are sure that `gedit-plugins` is installed, (re)open `gedit` and navigate to **Edit** → **Preferences** and select **Plugins** tab. Here you must to tick **Embedded Terminal**. Then when you will press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>, a terminal will appear in bottom pane:

[image: Embedded terminal in gedit]

Comment: I wrote in the question that this doesn't work in the Gedit version I'm using (3.8.3). Ctrl+F9 doesn't do a thing.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa Well, I'm  using Ubuntu 13.10 and that screen shoot was taken from Gedit 3.8.3. Try to reinstall Gedit.

Comment: I have re-installed Gedit. Ctrl+F9 still doesn't work, but now the Tools menu is gone. How can I get it back?

Comment: @LuísdeSousa How did you reinstalled? Use: `sudo apt-get purge gedit*` to uninstall everything related to `gedit`. Then install using `sudo apt-get install gedit gedit-common gedit-plugins`

Comment: I did something similar, but I tried again the way you suggest. Still I have no Tools menu nor the Bottom Panel. Is there any other version of GEdit packaged for 13.10?

Comment: I finally got the Bottom Panel and the Tools menu back by doing the following: 1) sudo apt-get purge gedit* 2) sudo apt-get autoremove 3) restart 4) sudo apt-get install gedit gedit-common gedit-plugins. I don't understand why it worked this way, but now GEDit is back to normal. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: @luis-de-sousa I think, in your steps that the restart is not necessary.

Comment: I believe the restart is unnecessary, but that was the procedure I took. I'm marking the answer as correct in any case, whatever was wrong with my system it probably isn't a common issue.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install `gedit-plugins` and `gedit-developer-plugins` from Ubuntu Software Center.
2. From within the Text Editor (gedit) application go to *Edit* → *Preferences* → *Plugins* → *Embedded Terminal*.
3. Restart gedit and after that just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> and you will get a terminal embedded in gedit.

I tried this in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

A more detailed answer from:

- [How to debug c programs by gedit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/728306/how-to-debug-c-programs-by-gedit/1082769#1082769)

## Gedit Plug-ins

### Use `gedit` external terminal plug-in

You can use `gedit` with terminal plugin. The steps are fairly straight-forward:

1. Enable "Universe" repository
2. Install `gedit-plugins`
3. Activate "Embedded Terminal"
4. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to open terminal
5. Other `gedit` plug-ins

### Step 1. Enable "Universe" repository

The first step is to ensure `Universe` repository is activated from `Settings`->`Software & Updates`->`Ubuntu Software` and ensure the third option is checked:

[image: gedit plugins repository.png]

### Step 2. Install `gedit-plugins`

Install `gedit-plugs` with the command:

```
sudo apt install gedit-plugins
```

### Step 3. Activate "Embedded Terminal"

Open `gedit` (don't use `sudo`) and select `Edit`->`Preferences`->`Plugins` and check off `Embedded Terminal`:

[image: gedit embedded terminal.png]

### Step 4. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to open terminal

In the GIF below we use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to get a tiny window with the command prompt. Use the mouse to click and drag the dividing line up to reveal an approximate size of 24x80.

The colors are dreadful! (with default `gedit` color scheme). I was just learning this as creating the answer so my mouse movements are slow below...

[image: gedit open terminal.gif]

### Step 5. Other `gedit` plug-ins

As mentioned in Step 4., you can grab the separator bar to make the terminal window bigger. Here's what it looks like in a normal picture ((not a GIF).

There are three other plug-ins I currently use in the `gedit` coding window:

- plug-in to display 80 character cut-off with different background color
- plug-in to display entire document in thumbnail you can drag to quickly go to code section
- Highlight matching brackets

Additionally there is an external add-on I'd like to install for `shellcheck` linter / checker that shows bash code errors. I haven't searched for a lint checker for other languages but obviously you can enter `gcc` and other commands directly into `gedit` terminal window.

[image: gedit teriminal line wrap.png]

For further reading please see:

- [Code completion for gedit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084602/code-completion-for-gedit/1084697#1084697)
- [Useful Gedit plugins for programmers - HowtoForge](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/three-useful-gedit-plugins-for-programmers/)
- [gedit: Add Python / C++ Autocomplete Support - nixCraft](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/gedit-python-c-cpp-autocomplete-plugin/)
- [5 Must-Have Gedit Plugins for Programmers | Yaser Sulaiman's Blog](https://yaserxp.wordpress.com/2008/09/03/5-must-have-gedit-plugins-for-programmers/)
- [How to C program in gedit - Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-C-program-in-gedit)