# How to debug c programs by gedit?

Tags: gedit, c, debugging

Is it possible to debug our programs written in c by gedit text editor ?
If not, how can i do it ?

Comment: **Close voters**:  The question is **not off-topic** because it relates to software that comes with Ubuntu. It does not ask general programming type of question !

Comment: thats true sorry about it i  was just wondering if it is possible to do that !

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about - you're in the right place, everything is OK

Comment: Do you know what are those third-party debugger plugins for python ? i mean this : https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/ThirdPartyPlugins-v3.0 @Serg

Comment: From what I read , most of those are markup and editing plugins, indentation plugins, but there is one for debugging. Never tried none, though. Personally I use `vim` and command line compilers/interpreters for 99% of the stuff I do.

Comment: Gedit is not a debugger, gdb is, and their may be a plug-in to gedit to make interfacing with gdb easier, is that what you are asking for? In your second question what is "it"? debugging? If it is "debugging" your question is far too broad.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`gedit` is a text editor - it will color the syntax but won't help you compile or debug it. What I suggest you use is `geany`. It is a very simple, very easy to use IDE, which you can use to write,compile, and debug. It's available through either Software Center or `sudo apt-get install geany`

Comment: Besides `geany` there is MS visual studio (or visual code?) which is getting good reviews as of late. Sorry don't have the link nor remember the product names exactly. Another +1 though for saying it can't be done in `gedit` :)

Comment: BTW I added an answer on what `gedit` can do, evenh it isn't much compared to professional editors like `geany`. However it is addressing OP's question which I think it is fair.

Answer (score 1):

## Gedit Plug-ins

### Use `gedit` external terminal plug-in

You can use `gedit` with terminal plugin. The steps are fairly straight-forward:

1. Enable "Universe" repository
2. Install `gedit-plugins`
3. Activate "Embedded Terminal"
4. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to open terminal
5. Other `gedit` plug-ins

### Step 1. Enable "Universe" repository

The first step is to ensure `Universe` repository is activated from `Settings`->`Software & Updates`->`Ubuntu Software` and ensure the third option is checked:

[image: gedit plugins repository.png]

### Step 2. Install `gedit-plugins`

Install `gedit-plugs` with the command:

```
sudo apt install gedit-plugins
```

### Step 3. Activate "Embedded Terminal"

Open `gedit` (don't use `sudo`) and select `Edit`->`Preferences`->`Plugins` and check off `Embedded Terminal`:

[image: gedit embedded terminal.png]

### Step 4. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to open terminal

In the GIF below we use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to get a tiny window with the command prompt. Use the mouse to click and drag the dividing line up to reveal an approximate size of 24x80.

The colors are dreadful! (with default `gedit` color scheme). I was just learning this as creating the answer so my mouse movements are slow below...

[image: gedit open terminal.gif]

### Step 5. Other `gedit` plug-ins

As mentioned in Step 4., you can grab the separator bar to make the terminal window bigger. Here's what it looks like in a normal picture ((not a GIF).

There are three other plug-ins I currently use in the `gedit` coding window:

- plug-in to display 80 character cut-off with different background color
- plug-in to display entire document in thumbnail you can drag to quickly go to code section
- Highlight matching brackets

Additionally there is an external add-on I'd like to install for `shellcheck` linter / checker that shows bash code errors. I haven't searched for a lint checker for other languages but obviously you can enter `gcc` and other commands directly into `gedit` terminal window.

[image: gedit teriminal line wrap.png]

For further reading please see:

- [Code completion for gedit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084602/code-completion-for-gedit/1084697#1084697)
- [Useful Gedit plugins for programmers - HowtoForge](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/three-useful-gedit-plugins-for-programmers/)
- [gedit: Add Python / C++ Autocomplete Support - nixCraft](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/gedit-python-c-cpp-autocomplete-plugin/)
- [5 Must-Have Gedit Plugins for Programmers | Yaser Sulaiman's Blog](https://yaserxp.wordpress.com/2008/09/03/5-must-have-gedit-plugins-for-programmers/)
- [How to C program in gedit - Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-C-program-in-gedit)

Comment: Code highlighting plugins can be useful for  debugging syntax and having console open next to editor is pretty much what all IDEs do, so to some extent you have turned gedit into an IDE. Very nice

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy As always thanks for the complement and no doubt sole up-vote. I added a link in this answer to a new answer just posted on C/HTML/CSS Code Completion using `gedit` with `snippets` plug-in. Highly useful and popular plug-in: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084602/code-completion-for-gedit/1084697#1084697

Answer (score 0):

gedit  your required file.c creates a new  file ,where you can type your code.
 You can debug it by compiling the code

If you are using gcc compiler then
 cc your program.c