# Is there a text editor that can run shell scripts?

Tags: scripts, text-editor

I will often change a small script in gedit and then run it from a terminal. Isn't there a simple text editor with a "Run" button or something to streamline this? Even in Eclipse it's not trivial. I'm looking for specific suggestions on which text editors support this or how they can be extended to support this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to activate the Gedit terminal plugin?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370138/how-to-activate-the-gedit-terminal-plugin-on-ubuntu-13-10)

Comment: Geany has an 'Execute' button, also F5 key for the same purpose. This works for scripts on my system...

Comment: @andrew.46 why you are not posting it as an answer then :  )

Comment: @karel That works in a way, it's not a button but I like the light-weight approach compared to Geany. I'm afraid the question itself is rather hard to find though using the search function, as it's really specific.

Comment: Geany can batch edit 50 html files at the same time and even open them all at the same time in a web browser to view the changes. Geany is that lightweight.

Comment: @karel I meant light-weight in terms of useability/GUI, not the performance. Would still make a great answer, as would suggesting the gedit terminal plugin!

Comment: While editing using `vim`, hit `Esc` and type `:sh` and Enter, when done hit `Ctrl-D` and you'll get back to your `vim` session.

Comment: @Yaron Please post that as answer, thanks in advance!

Comment: @αғsнιη Good point: done :)

Comment: You are already using `gedit` and it can do this as answer below shows.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Yep! A couple of great answers here but I chose yours now since I'm already using gedit and favouring it for its simplicity.

Comment: I use jupyter for this kind of work install anaconda navigator you open jupyter lab from it that gives this kind of feature

Comment: Emacs - can do everything :)

Comment: @karel and **other Close Voters** this is not a duplicate of *gedit terminal plugin* because OP is asking for all text editors and the most upvoted answer doesn't even reference `gedit`. The fact the accept answer is for `gedit`  is merely a lucky coincidence.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From:

- [How to debug c programs by gedit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/728306/how-to-debug-c-programs-by-gedit/1082769#1082769)

## Gedit Plug-ins

### Use `gedit` external terminal plug-in

You can use `gedit` with terminal plugin. The steps are fairly straight-forward:

1. Enable "Universe" repository
2. Install `gedit-plugins`
3. Activate "Embedded Terminal"
4. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to open terminal
5. Other `gedit` plug-ins

### Step 1. Enable "Universe" repository

The first step is to ensure `Universe` repository is activated from `Settings`->`Software & Updates`->`Ubuntu Software` and ensure the third option is checked:

[image: gedit plugins repository.png]

### Step 2. Install `gedit-plugins`

Install `gedit-plugs` with the command:

```
sudo apt install gedit-plugins
```

### Step 3. Activate "Embedded Terminal"

Open `gedit` (don't use `sudo`) and select `Edit`->`Preferences`->`Plugins` and check off `Embedded Terminal`:

[image: gedit embedded terminal.png]

### Step 4. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to open terminal

In the GIF below we use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to get a tiny window with the command prompt. Use the mouse to drag the dividing line up.

[image: gedit terminal plugin.gif]

### Step 5. Other `gedit` plug-ins

As mentioned in Step 4., you can grab the separator bar to make the terminal window bigger. Here's what it looks like in a normal picture ((not a GIF).

There are three other plug-ins I currently use in the `gedit` coding window:

- plug-in to display 80 character cut-off with different background color
- plug-in to display entire document in thumbnail you can drag to quickly go to code section
- Highlight matching brackets

[image: gedit teriminal line wrap.png]

For further reading please see:

- [Code completion for gedit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084602/code-completion-for-gedit/1084697#1084697)
- [Useful Gedit plugins for programmers - HowtoForge](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/three-useful-gedit-plugins-for-programmers/)
- [gedit: Add Python / C++ Autocomplete Support - nixCraft](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/gedit-python-c-cpp-autocomplete-plugin/)
- [5 Must-Have Gedit Plugins for Programmers | Yaser Sulaiman's Blog](https://yaserxp.wordpress.com/2008/09/03/5-must-have-gedit-plugins-for-programmers/)
- [How to C program in gedit - Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-C-program-in-gedit)

Comment: This is a horridly complicated solution. gVim is easier: `:term` for a terminal window. `:!` to run a single command. (shell completion and multi-tab is built-in to vim)

Comment: @noɥʇʎԀʎzɐɹƆ How is it complicated? You press `Ctrl`+`F9`. Then you can resize your window to split size of your `gedit` source code and your `gnome-terminal` output. The installation instructions don't have to be repeated every time before you press `Ctrl`+`F9` if that is what you are thinking.

Comment: But how do I run a single line from a code?

Comment: @Nip If I understand your question correctly... Highlight line of code and press `Ctrl`+`C`. Then move cursor to command entry line and press `Ctrl`+`V` followed by `Enter`.

Comment: Yes. But I was thinking in a way other than copy&paste. Something like when we press `Ctrl+R`   to run a line in RGUI (windows 10).

Answer (score 34):

## Option 1: use vim, emacs, geany, and many more!

In `vim` and use `:!bash file.sh` or just create a shortcut for it in `.vimrc`

In Emacs, you use `M-!`. So you hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and then press <kbd>!</kbd>. You can even pass text in your current buffer to a command by selecting what you want to pass to a command and then pressing `M-|`. So you can highlight your code and pass it to the command `bash`.

Every tool has it's own way!

## Option 2: use `find` and `entr`

Run this command so whenever ANY `.sh` file in the directory changes, it'll be run again automatically:

```bsh
find . -name '*.sh' | entr -cs file.sh
```

## Option 3: use combination of `tmux`, `vim`, and `entr` for live coding

I wrote this long ago for `c++` and then used it more in other languages and now you can use it for shell programming as well.

Here's how it'll look like:

[image: cppshell]

for the program to run all I have to do is to save it in vim (`:w`) and it'll run.

Save this in `~/bin/ide`:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/bash

tmpdir=""
template="simple"

for i in "$@"
do
case $i in
    -t=*|--template=*)
        template="${i#*=}"
    shift # past argument=value
    ;;

    -n=*|--name=*)
    dir="${i#*=}"
    mkdir -p ~/cppshells/$dir
    tmpdir=~/cppshells/$dir
    shift
    ;;

    -h|--help)
    echo "-n=*|--name=* \t\t the name of the project"
    echo "-t=*|--template \t\t the template to use"
    exit;
    ;;


    *)
        # nothing to do
    ;;
esac
done

if [ -z "$tmpdir" ]; then
    tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)
fi;

tmpdir=$(realpath ${tmpdir});
window="cpp-$1-$((1 + RANDOM % 10000000))"

if [ -z "$EDITOR" ]; then
    EDITOR="nvim";
fi;

template_dir="$(dirname $0)/templates/${template}"

if [ ! -d $template_dir ]; then
    echo "The specified template ($template) does not exists."
    exit;
fi;

tmux new -s ${window} -d -c "${tmpdir}"
tmux split-window -t ${window} -h
tmux select-pane -t ${window}.right
tmux resize-pane -t ${window}.right -R 18
tmux send-keys -t ${window}.left "cd ${tmpdir}" C-m
tmux send-keys -t ${window}.right "cd ${tmpdir}" C-m


# copy files if the directory does not exists
if [ `ls -A ${tmpdir} | wc -m` == "0" ]; then
    cp -nr $template_dir/* ${tmpdir}/.
fi;

# run build commands
if [ -f ${template_dir}/Makefile ]; then # make
    tmux send-keys -t ${window}.right "find . -name '*.cpp' | entr -cs 'make -j8 && ./a.out'" C-m
        tmux send-keys -t ${window}.left "${EDITOR} ${tmpdir}/main.cpp" C-m
elif [ -f ${template_dir}/CMakeLists.txt ]; then # CMake
    mkdir -p ${tmpdir}/build
    cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -B${tmpdir}/build -S${tmpdir}
    tmux send-keys -t ${window}.right "find . -name '*.cpp' | entr -cs 'make -j8 -Cbuild/ && ./build/a.out'" C-m
        tmux send-keys -t ${window}.left "${EDITOR} ${tmpdir}/main.cpp" C-m
elif [ -f ${template_dir}/main.py ]; then # Python
        chmod +x ${tmpdir}/main.py
    tmux send-keys -t ${window}.right "find . -name 'main.py' | entr -cs '${tmpdir}/main.py'" C-m
        tmux send-keys -t ${window}.left "${EDITOR} ${tmpdir}/main.py" C-m
elif [ -f ${template_dir}/main.sh ]; then # Bash
        chmod +x ${tmpdir}/main.sh
    tmux send-keys -t ${window}.right "find . -name 'main.sh' | entr -cs '${tmpdir}/main.sh'" C-m
        tmux send-keys -t ${window}.left "${EDITOR} ${tmpdir}/main.sh" C-m
fi;


tmux select-pane -t ${window}.left
tmux attach -t ${window}
```

Then create `~/bin/templates/simple` directories and put a simple `main.sh` file in them which will be your starting point when you run `ide` command. You can also create more and more templates (each one in a different directory in `~/bin/templates/` directory).

Add `/home/$USER/bin` to your path so you can run `ide`.

To run the script you can use these 3 ways:

- For simple tests: `ide` (it'll create a temp directory with `mktemp -d` command
- To save the file in `~/cppshell/[something]/` dir: `ide -n=something`
- To use a different template(starting point): `ide -t=not-simple -n=some_name`

As I said you could use this script to make shell like tool for running python, C++, bash, or even add your own.

**Update**: since I wrote this answer, I have updated my own version many times with new features and broader support. Here's a [link to GitHub page for this shell script](https://github.com/the-moisrex/linux-dotfiles/blob/master/bin/codeshell). You can also see more details on the [Readme page](https://github.com/the-moisrex/linux-dotfiles/blob/master/bin/README.md).

Comment: In vim, you can do `:w !bash` so it works even if the buffer is not saved or does not even have a filename.

Comment: @JoL Does that write the file as an input stream to the bash executable? I can see how it could be useful (more than just running the file).

Comment: @JohnHamilton Yes, it pipes the contents of the buffer to the stdin of the command. There's also `:r !cmd` to read the stdout of a command into the buffer.

Comment: Or in vim, pass the current filename to bash: `:!bash %` -- see `:help :!`

Answer (score 13):

If you're comfortable with vim, you can execute

```
:w !bash
```

(sub your shell of choice) and that will execute the script in the current buffer.

In a graphical environment, I use VS Code.  It's a lightweight IDE that's extensible, has built-in GIT support, and an integrated terminal.

Answer (score 9):

You can use Kate, it needs konsole to work:

```
sudo apt install kate konsole
```

Then in:

Kate ⇒ Configure ⇒ Application ⇒ Plugins and check the Terminal tool view checkbox.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8):

In Emacs you can use `Ctrl-C` `Ctrl-X` for that.

Answer (score 6):

One excellent option is to use my constant companion, the text editor Geany. By default there is an 'Execute' button which is also tied by default to the key <kbd>F5</kbd> that runs shell scripts from within the main editor window.

Here is a screenshot of Geany running a simple update script after it has been edited:

[image]

Observe as well the 'Tree Browser' plugin for Geany at the left of the screen which facilitates the selection of *all* of the scripts in my `~/bin` folder.

Answer (score 5):

**Update**: Atom is dead as of December 15, 2022.

I'm now using [VSCodium](https://vscodium.com/) (a distro of [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)), which is largely similar to Atom, especially after some customization. I'm using [Code Runner](https://open-vsx.org/extension/formulahendry/code-runner) (to replace `script` and `script-runner`) and [shellcheck](https://open-vsx.org/extension/timonwong/shellcheck) (to replace `linter-shellcheck`) as well as the [Jupyter extension](https://open-vsx.org/extension/ms-toolsai/jupyter) (to replace Hydrogen).

You might also consider [Pulsar](https://pulsar-edit.dev/), which is supposed to be a direct successor to Atom, though I haven't tried it myself.

---

### Atom + script

You could use [Atom](https://atom.io/) editor with the [`script` package](https://atom.io/packages/script). Once you set it up, simply press <kbd>F5</kbd> (with nothing selected) to run the script. It will use the shebang to determine what interpreter to run. Then press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to close the output pane.

Atom is not super lightweight, but it's also not super heavy. It also offers other packages like [`linter-shellcheck`](https://atom.io/packages/linter-shellcheck) to help with writing and debugging code. `script` also supports many other languages including Python, Perl, and HTML.

To install Atom, use the official .deb installer of the [latest release](https://github.com/atom/atom/releases/latest).

#### script-runner

Alternatively, the [`script-runner` package](https://atom.io/packages/script-runner) works similarly to `script`, but features a full terminal, so you can provide input on stdin for example. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to start it, then close the pane when you're done.

#### Hydrogen

Just to mention, for more programming-type stuff, [Hydrogen](https://atom.io/packages/hydrogen) can be used to run code interactively, just like Jupyter.

Answer (score 5):

I am not exactly sure what specific shell commands you need to run,
but [**Visual Studio Code**](https://code.visualstudio.com/) is becoming the current standard for a lightweight IDE.

A quick search brings me [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/9qbbcs/is_there_a_way_to_run_a_bash_scriptcommand_from/), where somebody asked, "Is there a way to run a bash script/command from VS Code?" (2018-10-22), with the answers being:

> https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks
>
> Yes, you can set up tasks. You can also specify a particular as the default build task

<sup>-- [/u/TG__](https://www.reddit.com/user/TG__) - [permalink](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/9qbbcs/is_there_a_way_to_run_a_bash_scriptcommand_from/e882mv1/)</sup>

> Code has a command prompt built in.

<sup>-- [/u/cornystool](https://www.reddit.com/user/cornystool) - [permalink](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/9qbbcs/is_there_a_way_to_run_a_bash_scriptcommand_from/e883q9e/)</sup>

Later on for the case that all you're looking for is an integrated shell where you can just type `./script.sh`

---

I scrolled through all the other answers and don't really agree. Sure, people that are used to their respective editors (vim, emacs, vi, gedit, notepad++, Atom, etc) will always point you towards their favorite.

But from multiple years in the coding industry and having tested out a lot of the newer editors, such as Atom, Sublime Text, etc. VS Code just shines through. It is what Atom always wanted to be.

It's tiny, fast, cross-platform, extensible, and almost fully customizable to your likings. If you want to be able to deliver fast results in a very productive, fun and welcoming personal environment, VS Code is my definite recommendation for you.

It's from the era where microsoft flicked a big switch in their organisation, targeting open-source, cross-platform and a much more friendly attitude towards foreign systems.
And it's damn noticable the people working on the editor have had some shitty experiences with their predecessing tools of choice and decided to make those things better from scratch.

Oh yeah. It's also free.

Comment: Thanks. For an IDE I'm still sticking with Eclipse, mainly because of the dead simple way I can reference Python projects there (also habit, FLOSS...). I've tried twice to migrate to VS Code and it is a sleek piece of software for sure. Everything makes sense! However for simply changing a path in a script and running it, I'd still prefer gedit with its ~3 buttons.

Answer (score 4):

Under vim/gvim, [autocommands](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/12.html) ([autocmd-use](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#autocmd-use)) are useful for this kind of workflow such that vim (and so shell) commands can be run on specific file/buffer events - avoiding the step of you having to trigger them manually.

As an example

```
:au BufWritePost,FileWritePost * silent :!( cd /path/to/somewhere && ./my-shell-command with some args; )
```

This runs `./my-shell-command ...` every time you write out/save the file. The caveat is that the output is not seen in the editor itself (as this requires a separate shell window). This may or may not be what you need.

Extending the concept to make it useful (making use of vim-tmux for e.g. to hold the stdout/stderr output), the above would become something like so

```
:au BufWritePost,FileWritePost * silent :Tmux ( cd /path/to/somewhere && bats my-tests.bats && ./my-script with some args; )
```

which personally is quite powerful if most of the workflow can be automated (code, test, run, repeat) so that you just focus on the task of writing the code.

Answer (score 4):

I use sublime as my main text editor and never had to use a build command in there but you can use its build system to run the bash file.

I can't test this exact command right now as I'm on Windows, but this should do the job ([Source](https://biancatamayo.me/blog/2017/06/29/mini-blog-how-to-run-currently-opened-bash-script-in-sublime-text-3/)):

> Open the command palette (usually Ctrl-Shift-P, or under Tools menu).
>   Choose "Build: New Build System".
>
> Replace file contents with:
>
> ```
> {
>     "cmd"       : ["bash", "$file"],
>     "selector"  : "source.shell" 
> }
> ```
>
> Save it as bash.sublime-build in the suggested directory, which should be anywhere in Sublime's *Packages* directory.

Then all you need to do is press Ctrl-B to "build" your bash file (yeah, you're actually just running it).

Some explanation, "cmd" portion is the actual command that is run, you can run any command with any parameter that Sublime supports. The second part, "selector", is what file types this build system will be run for, which is just "shell" files.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs has these `shell`-related functions: (NOTE: There is a learning curve with Emacs)

```
async-shell-command       M-&
   Execute string COMMAND asynchronously in background.
compilation-shell-minor-mode  M-x ... RET
   Toggle Compilation Shell minor mode.
eshell                M-x ... RET
   Create an interactive Eshell buffer.
eshell-command            M-x ... RET
   Execute the Eshell command string COMMAND.
eshell-mode           M-x ... RET
   Emacs shell interactive mode.
eshell-report-bug         M-x ... RET
   Report a bug in GNU Emacs.
gdb-shell-minor-mode          M-x ... RET
   Minor mode to add gdb features to shell mode.
idlwave-shell             M-x ... RET
   Run an inferior IDL, with I/O through buffer
   `(idlwave-shell-buffer)'.
minibuffer-default-add-shell-commands M-x ... RET
   Return a list of all commands associated with the current file.
shell                 M-x ... RET
   Run an inferior shell, with I/O through BUFFER (which defaults to
   `*shell*').
shell-command             <menu-bar> <tools> <shell>, M-!
   Execute string COMMAND in inferior shell; display output, if any.
shell-command-on-region       <menu-bar> <tools> <shell-on-region>, M-|
   Execute string COMMAND in inferior shell with region as input.
shell-current-directory       M-x ... RET
   Create a shell pertaining to the current directory.
shell-script-mode         M-x ... RET
   Major mode for editing shell scripts.
```

Or, you could use `make`, also with a learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

While editing using `vim`, hit `Esc` and type `:sh` and `Enter`, when done hit `Ctrl-D` and you'll get back to your `vim` session.

Thank you all.